# How can I get the size of the embedded fonts?

Tags: pdf

I have a private PDF document which has about 0.6MB, but when I watermark it with PyPDF2 it grows to 12 MB (the watermarking document is < 0.4MB). I think that this is related to compression, but I don't understand how.

It especially confuses me why the original PDF is so huge (uncompressed).:

- No images
- No embedded files
- Just 15 pages and the extracted text has 1467 characters

I was thinking that it might be embedded fonts:

```
$ pdffonts example.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
AAAAAB+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
AAAAAC+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      13  0
AAAAAD+MyriadPro-Regular             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      14  0
AAAAAE+MyriadPro-Regular             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      15  0
AAAAAF+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      16  0
AAAAAG+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      17  0
AAAAAH+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      18  0
AAAAAI+OpenSans-Bold                 TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      19  0
AAAAAJ+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      20  0
AAAAAK+OpenSans-Italic               TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      21  0
AAAAAL+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      31  0
AAAAAM+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      35  0
AAAAAN+MyriadPro-Regular             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      36  0
AAAAAO+MyriadPro-Regular             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      37  0
AAAAAP+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      38  0
AAAAAQ+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      39  0
AAAAAR+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      40  0
AAAAAS+OpenSans-Bold                 TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      41  0
AAAAAT+OpenSans-Regular              TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no      42  0
AAAAAU+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     53  0
AAAAAV+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     54  0
AAAAAW+Arial-ItalicMT                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     60  0
```

How can I check the (uncompressed) size of the embedded fonts?

Comment: Please post sample PDF files (small no watermark, large with watermark) so we can take a look at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
mutool extract example.pdf
```

you can extract all images / fonts.

In my case, the sum of all fonts (and two images I missed) was 0.3 kB... so my search continues.